# Java в сопоставлении с С#

Tags: .net, java, c#

Кто чего знает о преимуществах/недостатках данных языков, прошу поделиться. Нужна не религиозная война, а грамотные пояснения с указанием тех или иных особенностей и возможностей библиотек (можно со ссылками).

Answer (score 4):

Вначале изучил C#, понравился. Но, после попытки написания кроссплатформенного приложения для дипломной работы, понял, что в c# кроссплатформенностью и не пахнет. Поэтому выбрал Java.

Оба языка хорошие, удобные. Java выигрывает, если ты хочешь создавать кроссплатформенное приложение. В остальном, мои опыты показали, что программы написанные на яве и с# работают примерно одинаково (хотя проги, использующие OpenGL на c#, работают быстрее для одной платформы, то есть, если прога написана и собрана .net, то прога хорошо работает в windows, если mono, то в linux).

Дополнительные плюсы Явы - можно программировать под сотовые телефоны, включая Андроид.

Есть [описание различий](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_C_Sharp_%D0%B8_Java) на вики и [Сравнение синтаксиса](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html), так же на вики есть [описание Java API](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_Java_API).

Comment: У C# тоже плюс этот есть;) windows mobile и грядущий windows phone 7.

Comment: Надеюсь он ещё долго будет грясти :) Я вспоминаю эту систему с ужасом.

Comment: Что так? По мне так очень удобная платформа для разработки.. Привычная .Net библиотеки +  очень вкусненький и интересный XNA.

Comment: Она ужасна с пользовательской точки зрения

Comment: Есть еще Xamarin

Answer (score 3):

По большому счету языки в синтаксическом плане почти одинаковы. Выбор стоит сделать, внимательно изучив библиотеки и фреймворки для обоих языков. На мой взгляд, Java обладает большей базой библиотек, что, возможно, вызвано поддержкой Java со стороны Google, IBM, Oracle, Apache. Но решение нужно принять исходя из того, что вы хотите программировать.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы собираетесь писать приложения под Windows и только, то смело выбирайте C#. 
Хотите охватить больше платформ тогда начинайте изучать Java.

> Дополнительные плюсы Явы - можно программировать под сотовые телефоны, включая Андроид.

На C# можно писать под Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное что бы понять разницу между С# и Java, необходимо немного истории.Сначала был Java. Язык, который декларировался как не зависящий от платформы(процессора,операционной системы). Для реализации независимости, была предложена виртуальная машина JVM(Java Virtual Maсhinе). Это эмуляция некого процессора, который можно запустить на любой платформе(для которой она имеется). Спецификация JVM требует поддержки всех Java библиотек.
Фирма Microsoft сначала придерживалась данной спецификации, но потом предложила разработчикам использовать свои классы, с применением натив библиотек mfc42.dll. На что Sun Microsystem подала судебный иск, с требованием либо поменять название JVM, либо придерживаться спецификации. Microsoft изменила название JVM(Java Virtual Maсhinе) на CLR(Common Language Runtime).А слегка изменив спецификацию самого языка получила новый язык для своей платформы Windows, С#.

Comment: такую точку зрения первый раз слышу - забавно сказано, но показывает что автор не знает что такое CLR и в чем отличие от JVM. А главное отличие в том что что у явы "виртуальная машина", а у .net вполне себе настоящая - код транслируется (может и на лету частично или полностью, может и заранее) в код (в нативный код) того процессора (среды) в которой происходит исполнение. Соответственно, скорость исполнения программ .net превосходит java.

Comment: А главное отличие в том что что у явы "виртуальная машина", а у .net вполне себе настоящая - код транслируется    -   это полная фигня. Все нормаьлные виртуальные машины используют JIT-компилятор, который как раз и транслирует на лету из пседо-инструкций в реальные. Разумеется, .NET и Java машины умеются это делать. Так что разница не в этом совсем.

Comment: Что же до скорости выполнения, то тут 50 на 50. Я видел много примеров, когда .NET быстрее, а видел и много примеров, когда Java.

Comment: Microsoft изменила название JVM(Java Virtual Maсhinе) на CLR(Common Language Runtime)   - это тоже фигня. Если вы посмотрите на псевдо-инструкции виртуальных машин, то вы обнаружите, что дело не просто в переименовании.

Comment: то что код в .net может транслироваться по разному не "фигня", а реальность. Программу на .net можно скомпилировать сразу (во время компиляции, а не во время запуска программы) в реальный код для реального процессора. И в этом случае, полученная программа не будет ничем отличаться от любой другой скомпилированной программы.

Comment: Но вы то сформулировали это так, будто способность к нативной кодогенерации - исключительная способность .NET. Кроме того, если вы сгенерируете для .NET приложения нативный код, то вы потеряете его переносимость, а скорость останется почти такой же, как и при генерации на лету (JIT). Но вы пошли дальше: вы использовали эту неточность, чтобы устроить холивар.

Comment: не сочиняй @cy6erGn0m! что хотел то и сказал, если вы читаете текст так своеобразно, то это исключительно ваша проблема. Не смешивайте два различных подхода к компиляции, "на лету" и во время компиляции. Я сказал что в .net есть и то и другое, в java только одно - "на лету". И это связано с работой "виртуальной машины".

Answer (score -1):

В Java не разбираюсь особо там просто код пишите, в C# можно сразу как в Delphi рисовать все. 
Java требует JVM, C# требует .Net или Mono.
В этом вся разница.

Comment: >> в C# можно сразу как в Delphi рисовать все   - что всё рисовать? Вы имеете в виду дизайнер форм? Этого добра и в Java достаточно. Правда я всё больше убеждаюсь, что это и недостаток одновременно. Кроме того, в конечно итоге важно не это, а область применения, о чём уже было отвечено выше.

Comment: Области применения ограничиваются написанными библиотеками.
У C# есть .Net библиотеки у Java свои.
При компиляции Java получится байт код который будет работать медленнее из-за интерпретации.
При компиляции C# - машинный код, привязанный к .Net или Mono.

В итоге по области применения они не различаются, все дело в руках и то в каком языке вам комфортнее писать.

Да и не забудьте отметить наиболее подходящий ответ вашему вопросу.

Comment: Формошлепство в действии.
Ты совершенно не понимаешь сути С#.

Comment: @Flux, может хватит холиварить? Ещё троллей не хватало. На кой чёрт поднимать старую закрытую тему наверх, да ещё измусоленную миллион раз.