# Отличие C# от Java

Tags: java, c#

Появилась необходимость быстрого ознакомления с языком Java, но при первом взгляде много общего с C# и ему подобными. То есть изучать циклы, классы и прочее заново я не собираюсь. Может есть какая нибудь сравнительная статья или материал характеризующий различия между этими языками

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java в сопоставлении с С#](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1393/java-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Сравнение C Sharp и Java](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_C_Sharp_%D0%B8_Java), например.